# Whats wrong with this regex

Tags: regex

I have been solving quizes from regex101.com. One of the problems begins like this

> For every occurence of the char #, backreference the previous character.
>   Example: for the text `a#bc# -#`, set backreferences with a, c and -.
>   You are not allowed to consume the hash character.

My solution to this problem is `(\S)[?=#]` and I think it's correct. Works well with `a#bc# -#` and `abcd#`.

But the site does not accept my answer. It tells me that I am consuming the hash character. I don't know what's wrong. I am not consuming hash character and this works perfectly in my java program.

Comment: Do you understand what would `[` and `]` imply in regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error:

```
(\S)(?=#)
```

(Don't use square brackets for [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - `[?=#]` means "one of the letters `?`, `=` or `#`)

Comment: thanks a lot. May be i should go back to learning basic of regex before solving this quiz. I didnt knew what [] do..